# Add quotes around alpha characters in alphanumeric strings using T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, split, quotes, alphanumeric

I want to add quotes around alphabets in an alphanumeric string. For eg: If my string is 8AB8973, the output expected is 8'AB'8973. There is no specific pattern in which the numbers and characters will occur. I tried to run the following piece of code I found on StackOverflow, but it adds a space between numbers and alphabets, when I try to replace the space with quotes, the query takes forever to run.

```
    DECLARE @position INT;
    DECLARE @string VARCHAR(max);

    SET @string = '9FX8173'

    WHILE 1 = 1
      BEGIN
          SET @position = (SELECT Min(position)
                           FROM   (VALUES (Patindex('%[^ 0-9][0-9]%', @string)),
                                          (Patindex('%[0-9][^ 0-9]%', @string))) AS T(position)
                           WHERE  T.position > 0);

          IF @position IS NULL
            BREAK;

          SET @string = Stuff(@string, @position + 1, 0, ' ');
       END

       PRINT @string
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to replacing space with a quote in the STUFF function, you need to do the same in the `PATINDEX` search expressions:

```
DECLARE @position INT;
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(max);

SET @string = '9FX8173';

WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN
    SET @position = (
        SELECT MIN(position)
        FROM (VALUES (PATINDEX('%[^''0-9][0-9]%', @string)),
                     (PATINDEX('%[0-9][^''0-9]%', @string))) AS T(position)
        WHERE  T.position > 0);

    IF @position IS NULL
        BREAK;

    SET @string = STUFF(@string, @position + 1, 0, '''');
END

PRINT @string;
```

Comment: How do i include a quote before the first character if the string starts with a char, for eg: TAX000964, the above string starts with characters, for this the expected result is 'TAX'000964. The current query mentioned above gives me TAX'000964.

Comment: Also, it doesnt take care of the last character, for eg : 00140M, expected result would be 00140'M', however I am receiving 00140'M.

Answer (score 0):

For a purely set-based high performing solution you can use [PatternSplitCM](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/String+Manipulation/94365/).

**The function**

```
-- PatternSplitCM will split a string based on a pattern of the form 
-- supported by LIKE and PATINDEX 
-- 
-- Created by: Chris Morris 12-Oct-2012 
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.PatternSplitCM
(
  @List               VARCHAR(8000) = NULL,
  @Pattern            VARCHAR(50)
) RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING 
AS 
RETURN
    WITH numbers AS (
      SELECT TOP(ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@List), 0))
       n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
      FROM
      (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) d (n),
      (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) e (n),
      (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) f (n),
      (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) g (n))

    SELECT
      ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY MIN(n)),
      Item = SUBSTRING(@List,MIN(n),1+MAX(n)-MIN(n)),
      [Matched]
     FROM (
      SELECT n, y.[Matched], Grouper = n - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY y.[Matched],n)
      FROM numbers
      CROSS APPLY (
          SELECT [Matched] = CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(@List,n,1) LIKE @Pattern THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
      ) y
     ) d
     GROUP BY [Matched], Grouper
GO
```

**Solution**

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(max);

SET @string = '9FX81D73';

select newstring = 
(
  select case [matched] when 1 then  ''''+item+'''' else item end
  from dbo.PatternSplitCM(@string, '[a-zA-Z]')
  order by itemnumber
  for xml path('')
);
```

**Results**

```
newstring
----------------------
9'FX'81'D'73
```